# Ошибка когда параметр IDENTITY_INSERT имеет значение OFF WPF C# MS SQL

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Student studObj = new Student()
            {
                
                Name = TxbName.Text,
                special = CmbSpecial.SelectedItem as special,
                yearAdd = CmbYear.SelectedItem as yearAdd,
                FormTime = CmbForm.SelectedItem as FormTime,
                NameGroup = CmbGroup.SelectedItem as NameGroup
            };
            AppConnect.modelodb.Student.Add(studObj);
            AppConnect.modelodb.SaveChanges();
            //if (tumb.IsChecked == false)
            //{
            //    AppFrame.frameMain.GoBack();
            //}

            MessageBox.Show($"Студент {Name} успешно добавлен в список.", "Успех", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
            //MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка: " + ex.Message.ToString() + " Критическая ошибка работы приложения!" +
            //    " Возможно вы ввели неккоректные данные, проверьте правильность или обратитесь в техническую поддержку Minusinsk Education " +
            //    " по ссылке vk.com/mental_zheka", "Ошибка добавления", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

Добрый день, сообщество, выше дан код. При записи в базу, т.е. при нажатии кнопки срабатывает исключение:

> Невозможно вставить явное значение для столбца идентификаторов в
> таблице "Student", когда параметр IDENTITY_INSERT имеет значение OFF.

Что делать? Идентификатор в БД для этой таблицы включён и начинается с 1.

Comment: Мало информации, скорее всего что-то можно найти в AppConnect, можно конечно ещё выставить SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON) Но скорее всего это наоборот всё поломает

Comment: что-нибудь специфическое в классе Student относительно ID имеется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась банальным обновлением модели БД....